# Android: Como eliminar espaço entre cada entrada numa Spinner?

Tags: android

Tenho uma spinner onde pretendo colocar o nome dos horoscopos. No entanto, o nome dos horoscopos aparece com uma linha em branco a separar cada horoscopo quando "abro" a spinner. Mais ou menos assim:

```
-linha em branco-
Geminis
-linha em branco-
Cancer
-linha em branco-
```

Alguém me sabe dizer como posso diminuir o espaço que existe entre o nome de cada horoscopo?
O meu código é este:

```
strings.xml

<string-array name="horoscope_array">
        <item>Aquarius</item>
        <item>Pisces</item>
        <item>Aries</item>
        <item>Taurus</item>
        <item>Gemini</item>
        <item>Cancer</item>
        <item>Leo</item>
        <item>Virgo</item>
        <item>Libra</item>
        <item>Scorpius</item>
        <item>Sagitarius</item>
        <item>Capricorn</item>
    </string-array>

<string name="horoscope_prompt">Choose a Horoscope</string>
```

No meu `layout.xml` tenho:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:entries="@array/horoscope_array"
android:textColor="@color/orange"
android:prompt="@string/horoscope_prompt" />
```

Comment: Linha em branco?

Answer (score 0):

Olha, ai parece estar tudo ok, mas não sei como esta o sua classe, mas deve ser algo parecido com isto

```
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teuLayout);        
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.horoscope_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```